# Images too dark on device screen

Tags: android, graphics, png, android-canvas

I have recently started using .png images for my game, but on the device they are way too dark.

I use this code to get my images :

```
a=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red_ball);
atom_bmp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(a,60,60,false);
```

and then i draw them on canvas :

```
canvas.drawBitmap(atom_bmp,enemies[x].x-30,enemies[x].y-30, paint);
```

The resulting images are way darker than they appear on computer. How can that be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is related to [Gamma (good tutorial)](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/gamma-correction.htm) settings on the android device and the computer you used to make the images.  In short, the numerical values `0-255` of an RGB pixel are not linearly related to the brightness of a pixel on the screen.  The values are raised to a power `gamma` whose value varies on different systems.  `gamma` usually lies in the range `1.8 - 2.2`.  You can change the display gamma in Photoshop to match the android device, and then modify the images appropriately.  You should also make sure you're saving your images in the [sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srgb) color space and not something else like Adobe RGB.